# Remove docker containers and network only if they exists

Tags: docker, jenkins

In Jenkins I am trying to remove all my running containers and remove my network (called my-net), but only if they exists.

In one of the steps I have:

```
stage('test1') {
                  steps {
                         sh 'docker network create my-net'
                         sh 'docker build -t myimage1 .'
                         sh 'docker create --name mybackend--network my-net myimage1'
                         sh 'docker start mybackend'
                        }
        }
```

Before all stages I put this:

```
stage('Remove containers and network') {
      steps {
            sh 'docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)'
            sh 'docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)'
            sh 'docker network rm my-net'
      }
    }
```

This should remove all the running containers (as I don't have only one container running) and **my-net** network.

I used this to remove all running containers, because I don't know how to remove just the container with name **mybackend**, but only if it is running.

The problem is also with the network, if it is not running, it fails on this line:

```
 sh 'docker network rm my-net'
```

I also tried to put this removal step at the very end of all my steps, but in that case if the script fails somewhere, it doesn't reach the removal steps at the end.

So the question is, if I want to keep the removal as the first step, is there a way to:

- stop and remove container with name **mybackend** ONLY if it is running (and also remove the other one same way called e.g. mybackend2)
- remove **my-net** network, but ONLY if it exists

What I found when I investigated:

```
docker system prune
```

This should clean up all unused containers, networks, images. But in my case the network or container might be running, so it is not unused, so the only thing I want, is to remove my containers and network, if they are running.

Comment: You can use container's name (or in general, name of a resource) to remove it. If you named your container `mybackend`, you could use `docker container stop mybackend` to stop the container, and `docker container rm mybackend` to remove it.

Comment: To further extend my comment, you can also apply [filters](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering). For example, `docker container stop $(docker container ls -q -f "name=mybackend")` would stop all containers whose name begins with `mybackend`. As for the _only if_ parts of your question, I think you need some conditions in your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've found a solution, I put all the stuff in the post -> always step, which will run even if something fails.

```
   post {
        always {
            sh 'docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)'
            sh 'docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)'
            sh 'docker network rm my-net'
        }
    }
```